# Resource in REST API : To be or not to be?

Tags: rest

I have been reading about how resources should be modeled after nouns and how related resources should be represented in the URI.

**Short background:**

Let us say that I have to create a document for a **person**. The person data exists in an external application but we need to create **documents** in our application. The starting point for a document creation is to perform a search on person which will fetch the details of person from an external application and then we will create/save the details of both the document and the person in our database.I feel that in this case Person is a noun and hence a Resource irrespective of whether our application creates a new person or not.Even if the operation is not directly creating a new person it seems like document cannot exist without a person. So the create Documents URI should be a

```
POST /persons/personId/documents
```

which is more intuitive.

But there is a different suggestion that person is not really a resource here, the argument being that we are not modifying Person and hence the URI should be

```
/documents
```

So my questions:

1. Would be be right to say that Person is not a resource based on the arguement above ?
2. Isn't the first approach better/more intuitive for creating a document: `/persons/personId/documents`? The fact that a document will be created for a Person and a document cannot be created without a Person as such.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of misconceptions about REST, and people often engage in endless discussion about something that isn't really a problem in REST.

First, URI semantics are irrelevant in REST, so forget the noun/verb nonsense. I've seen people stressed out trying to figure out how to convert an action to a noun and an HTTP verb, and that's absolutely pointless. In REST, the whole URI is an atomic identifier, and the URI contents don't matter, only what is identified by the URI. Sure, we should put some effort on having clear and well-organized URIs, that clearly communicate the intent to the developer, but that's just a general good practice, not a REST constraint. There's no such thing as RESTful URI.  What makes an URI RESTful is how you obtain it, not how it looks like.

Second, URI semantics are irrelevant because [REST APIs must be hypertext driven](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven). Related resources should be represented by links in the resource representation itself, not in the URI, as your first phrase says. How your clients know the URI to create documents? Are they reading something like `/persons/<personid>/documents` in documentation and replacing `personid` with a value? Is that what you do when you join StackOverflow and want to read your questions? You check documentation for an URI template, get your user id, paste that into the URI placeholder? Of course not. You simply follow a link and you don't really care about what exactly the URI is. That's how REST works. Like the Web itself.

So, when your clients enter your API, they can have a root document which shows the representation of the `Person` resource associated with them and permanent link to that, and links to related resources, including documents. The documentation for the `Person` resource can explain how the `rel=documents` link points to a collection of `Document` resources associated with that person, and how POST'ing to that same URI creates a new `Document` resource. As you can see, what you are asking isn't really a problem in REST, because the "intuitive" thing to do is to follow a link. It can be `/persons/<personid>/documents` or anything else. What matters is how your client obtains those links.

Third, everything identified by an URI is a resource, and everything you are interacting with should have at least one URI. That means if you are interacting with something identified by anything other than an URI -- for instance, you are sending an id in the body --, and that thing you are interacting with is not reachable through an URI, then it's not a resource and you are doing something wrong.

So, in case the answer is not clear:

1. If you have an URI for Person, it's a resource. If you don't, it's not.
2. The only RESTful approach is to follow links, and the URI semantics won't matter. The more descriptive the URI is, the better, of course, but that's up to you, and not a REST constraint.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter where a Person is stored. You are designing an API which by definition is an interface that abstracts from storage backends.

The URL you propose is very RESTful since it correctly models the relatinship between person and document. In addition, this URL scheme has a segment for the collection resource of all persons (`/persons`) and one for the collection of all documents that belong to a document (`/persons/{personId}/documents`).

As long as you don't allow request like

```
POST /persons
```

or

```
PUT /person/{personId}
```

which would create a new person or alter an existing one, I can see no problem with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would say Person is a resource because it is possible to request information about a particular person: the documents they own.
2. Indeed to me it seems perfectly reasonable for URIs to express relationships between different resources.